# How do I report a sensitive security issue? 

Tags: security

In Ubuntu 10.04 (and perhaps later) there appears to be a serious vulnerability to a brute force dictionary attack on any Apache server that is using MySQL to validate user logins.

This issue means that neither fail2ban nor Apache mod_security detects the attack.

I would prefer not to list the detail here.

Could someone contact me or explain to me how I can report the problem without posting the vulnerability to the whole world?

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to file a bug against the package you're having an issue with. You can use [these instructions to report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Once all the data is collected LaunchPad will open a window and you can continue with the bug reporting process.

Alternatively, visit the LaunchPad Ubuntu page (`https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/<PACKAGENAME>`) then fill out the details.

Once a summary and duplicate detection have completed, but prior to submitting your report, there will be the following option at the bottom of the page that you will need to select:

[image]

Doing so will make this bug hidden and alert the security team.

Comment: I do not want to post the bug to the whole world. I would prefer that someone contacts me on my email.

Comment: OK now I read the end of your post. I will report it if it is hidden.

Comment: @paul It will only be visible to the maintainers and the security team.